# Are there any pitfalls pointing config sync to profile's config/install?

Tags: 8, configuration

Is this good practice? I have pointed my config sync to:

```
$config_directories['sync'] = 'profiles/PROFILENAME/config/install';
```

Experiments with `drush cex` have worked, allowing a cycle of UI changes, config export, and re-installation with the new changes.

We will not be going live with D8 for a while, so the team's plan is to use this method to gain familiarity with the config system and other parts of D8 using this simple method.

Comment: Just a note... During installation the following exported config causes install to break.
`core.extension.yml`, `file.setting.yml`, `update.setting.yml`.

Comment: While I'm not about to answer my own question yet. At this point I believe this practice will not be good practice based on my reading of [Review PreExistingConfigException special casing for install profile](https://www.drupal.org/node/2431157)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't think that is a good idea. default configuration is something else than the config sync folder. For example exported config has a UUID and system.site has a site UUID while default config shouldn't.

They are two different use cases. default config is for installing new sites and the config export is to deploy configuration between different installations of the *same* site.

What you might want to look into is https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer, a simple installer that allows to install based on an config export/sync folder.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, accepted answer. I've opted for a different directory, and using drush config-import of that directory after each site install (which currently requires this PR https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/1635)